# SQL Alchemy Problem : sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError

Tags: python, sql, sqlalchemy, foreign-keys, fastapi

the Error i am getting is this one (After tryig to test a GET for the user object, while creating CRUD Endpoint) :

> sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError: When initializing mapper Mapper[User(users)], expression 'Favorite' failed to locate a name ('Favorite'). If this is a class name, consider adding this relationship() to the <class 'app.schemas.user.User'> class after both dependent classes have been defined.

And here is my code :

```
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, String, ForeignKey
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base


Base = declarative_base()

class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = "users"

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, index=True)
    first_name = Column(String, index=True)
    last_name = Column(String, index=True)
    email = Column(String, index=True)
    password = Column(String, index=True)
    
    
    # ! here is the problem, but removing it will strip the
    # ! the possibility of navigating the tables.
    favorites = relationship('Favorite')
```

And for the Favorites :

```
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, ForeignKey
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship
from app.schemas.user import User
from app.schemas.article import Article
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base

Base = declarative_base()

class Favorite(Base):
    __tablename__ = "favorites"

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, index=True)
    id_user = Column(Integer, ForeignKey(User.__table__.c.id))
    id_article = Column(Integer, ForeignKey(Article.__table__.c.id))
    
    #user = relationship('User')    
    #article = relationship('Article', back_populates='favorites')
```

Here is the code i am using to create the tables :
from app.config.creds import DATABASE_URL

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker

from app.schemas.favorite import Base as FavoriteBase

from app.schemas.user import Base as UserBase
from app.schemas.article import Base as ArticleBase

engine = create_engine(DATABASE_URL)

ArticleBase.metadata.create_all(bind=engine)
print('Article table created!')
FavoriteBase.metadata.create_all(bind=engine)
print('Favorite table created!')
UserBase.metadata.create_all(bind=engine)
print('User table created!')  


SessionLocal = sessionmaker(autocommit=False, autoflush=False, bind=engine)

def get_db():
    db = SessionLocal()
    try:
        yield db
    finally:
        db.close()

print('Database setup complete!')
```

How can i solve the problem ? and is removing the    `favorites = relationship('Favorite)` "harmful" ?

I tried merging everything in one file, removing some relationships and all, only thing that works (but it isnt what i need from the One to many relationship) is to remove the line :    `favorites = relationship('Favorite)` .

Answer (score 2):

`SQLAlchemy` is looking for `Favorite` model in the same metadata object, where the `User` model is defined. But you link it to another metadata object (another `Base` object).

You have to use one `Base` object for all your models that have relationships.

Create `Base` in the separate module and import it to all your modules with models.

Comment: Indeed, that was the solution. Thank you so much !
(PS : Question, is it advised to use the same Base for all models ?)

Comment: If you don't need to separate these models to different databases (`engine`s), use one common `Base` object.